# Adding search to TableViewController and displaying results

Tags: iphone, swift, search, xcode7, ios9.1

So my problem is that I want to search for the names in the list of FirstSearch.swift but I want to display the image and the town in the search results too. I have no clue how to do it and I'm a bit new to programming in Swift. So could anyone please help me with my code

My FirstSearch.swift

```
import Foundation

class People {
class Input {
    let imageName: String
    let userName: String
    let userTown: String
    init(iName: String, uName: String, uTown: String){
        self.imageName = iName
        self.userName = uName
        self.userTown = uTown
    }
}

let peopleList = [
    Input(iName: "Habib.jpg", uName: "Habib Badiane", uTown: "Emden, Deutschland"),
    Input(iName: "John.jpg", uName: "John Adams", uTown: "Emden, Deutschland"),
    Input(iName: "Marcus.jpg", uName: "Marcus Dirks", uTown: "Emden, Deutschland"),
    Input(iName: "0.jpg", uName: "Tobias Tebben", uTown: "Emden, Deutschland"),
    Input(iName: "Neda.jpg", uName: "Neda Heidari", uTown: "Emden, Deutschland"),
    Input(iName: "Gudrun.jpg", uName: "Gudrun Burlefinger", uTown: "Emden, Deutschland")
]
```

}

My FirstSearchTableViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class FirstSearchTableViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating {

let people = People()
var filteredTableData = [String]()
var resultSearchController = UISearchController()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.resultSearchController = ({
        let controller = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        controller.searchResultsUpdater = self
        controller.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        controller.searchBar.sizeToFit()

        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = controller.searchBar

        return controller
    })()

    // Reload the table
    self.tableView.reloadData()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if (self.resultSearchController.active) {
        return self.filteredTableData.count
    }
    else {
        return people.peopleList.count
    }
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! FirstSearchTableViewCell

    let input = people.peopleList[indexPath.row]
    let image = UIImage(named: input.imageName)
    cell.profileImg.image = image
    cell.profileName.text = input.userName
    cell.profileCity.text = input.userTown



    // Configure the cell...

    if (self.resultSearchController.active) {
        cell.textLabel?.text = filteredTableData[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }
    else {
        cell.textLabel?.text = people.peopleList[indexPath.row]

    return cell
    }
}

func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController)
{
    filteredTableData.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

    let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF CONTAINS[c] %@", searchController.searchBar.text!)
    let array = (people.peopleList as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredicate)
    filteredTableData = array as! [String]

    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem is that your table function must identify the column that you wish to display. Look for some simple example code.

Each call to tableView will have to check for the column and the row. Your code can only return the name because it doesn't check for the column. The column's are identified by the name you assign them in IB (interface builder).
Here's an example

```
     if (tableColumn!.identifier == "name")
     {
        return artistSet!.itemAt(row,key:"name")
     }
     else if (tableColumn!.identifier == "image")
     {
         // etc
     }
```